# My directive stopped working when I started using ng-repeat with a different controller. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I followed this guide so I could have a nav bar on every page: http://tomaszdziurko.pl/2013/02/twitter-bootstrap-navbar-angularjs-component/

And it was working, until I created a separate controller to populate my bootstrap carousel. The thing is, my ng-repeat works fine, but when it does I can't see my navbar on that page. I can see it just fine on other pages. I believe this is a scoping issue, but I am not sure where.

This is what I have in the main body of this page:

```
<body>
    <reusable-navbar></reusable-navbar>

    <!-- Carousel Start -->
    <div id="main-carousel" class="carousel slide container" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <!--Must set this by hand-->
        <div class="item active">
                <img alt="" src="../Revamp/Images/carousel/1.jpg">
        </div>
        <!--Repeat through the rest-->
        <div ng-controller="carouselPhotoController">
            <div class="item" ng-repeat="source in source">
                    <img alt="" ng-src="{{source.source}}">
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
var carouselPhotoController=angular.module("revampApp", []);

carouselPhotoController.controller("carouselPhotoController", function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('../Revamp/Images/carousel/photos.json').success(function(photos){
        //Carousel photos
        $scope.source = photos;
    })
});
```

And the directive is identical to the one in that walk through, just with a different template. So how to I get it so my nav bar will show up AND I can use ng-repeat?

Comment: Not sure if this is it, but if you change "source in source" to something like 's in source' and then use ng-src={{s.source}} does it help?

Comment: Nope, no difference. I actually looked at the header, and apparently it depends on which order the import files come in:

`<!-- Directives-->
     <script src="revamp_pages/reusableNavBar.js"></script>
     <!-- Controllers -->
     <script src="Controllers/carouselPhotoController.js"></script>`
Which ever comes first does not load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are not recreating the app.

This creates a new app:

```
var carouselPhotoController=angular.module("revampApp", []);
```

But this only accesses an app already created (note the absence of the second parameter):

```
var carouselPhotoController=angular.module("revampApp");
```

Change the above line and it should work.

Comment: That was it thank you! Just curious, in what case would I want to create a new module instead of using the existing one?

Comment: Think in modules like if they were libraries. If you have a functionality that can be reused on other apps, then that's a good candidate for a module :)